# What does proposal 271 provide?

Tags: guard

Can anyone explain, in simple terms, [proposal  271](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/271-another-guard-selection.txt) for the new guard selection algorithm, implemented in Tor 0.3.x?

What makes it different from the previous guard selection algorithm? Is it the same behavior for hidden services and clients?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how a hidden service rendezvous circuit currently looks like:

```
                 -> middle_1 -> middle_A
                 -> middle_2 -> middle_B
                 -> middle_3 -> middle_C
                 -> middle_4 -> middle_D
   HS -> guard   -> middle_5 -> middle_E -> Rendezvous Point
                 -> middle_6 -> middle_F
                 -> middle_7 -> middle_G
                 -> middle_8 -> middle_H
                 ->   ...    ->  ...
                 -> middle_n -> middle_n
```

this proposal pins the two middles nodes to a much more restricted
set, as follows:

```
                              -> guard_3A_A
                 -> guard_2_A -> guard_3A_B
                              -> guard_3A_C -> Rendezvous Point
   HS -> guard_1
                              -> guard_3B_D
                 -> guard_2_B -> guard_3B_E
                              -> guard_3B_F -> Rendezvous Point

rotation period:
         (3 months)  (~11 days)  (12 hours)
```

Note that the third level guards are partitioned into buckets such that
they are only used with one specific second-level guard. In this way,
we ensure that even if an adversary is able to execute a Sybil attack
against the third layer, they only get to learn one of the second layer
Guards, and not all of them. This prevents the adversary from gaining
the ability to take their pick of the weakest of the second-level
guards for further attack.

In effect this means that it is much harder to mount guard discovery attacks, which will protect better Tor onion services.

Both clients and services will use this same algorithm to preserve the symmetry.

Comment: Um, I think you're describing the wrong proposal? You're describing [prop-247](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/247-hs-guard-discovery.txt) not [prop-271](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/271-another-guard-selection.txt).